# Extract value from array in PHP

Tags: php

I have a little problem that I can't get my head around. I am new to php. I want to extract the top_secret from here:

```
Array ( [headers] => Requests_Utility_CaseInsensitiveDictionary Object ( [data:protected] 
=> Array ( [content-type] => application/json; charset=UTF-8 [expires] => Sat, 01 Jan 2000 00:00:00
 GMT   [content-length] => 250 ) ) [body] => 

{"top_secret":"WELLTHISISTOPSECRETSONOONESHOULDEVERSEEIT","token_type":x,"expires_in":x} [response] => 
Array ( [code] => 200 [message] => OK ) [cookies] => Array ( ) [filename] => 
[http_response] => WP_HTTP_Requests_Response Object ( [response:protected] => 
Requests_Response Object ( [body] => 
{"top_secret":"WELLTHISISTOPSECRETSONOONESHOULDEVERSEEIT","token_type":x,"expires_in":x} [raw] => 
HTTP/1.1 200 OK Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8
{"top_secret":"WELLTHISISTOPSECRETSONOONESHOULDEVERSEEIT","token_type":"bearer","expires_in":x}
```

What I tried:

```
<?php
parse_str($response['body'], $response);
$field=$response['top_secret'];
echo $top_secret;
?>
```

But nothing appears. Any idea what I am doing wrong? I want to echo the following string:

`WELLTHISISTOPSECRETSONOONESHOULDEVERSEEIT`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `parse_str` function parses strings as if they were the **query string passed via a URL**, e.g. something like `first=value&arr[]=foo+bar&arr[]=baz`.

But your `$response['body']` is apparently a JSON string. You will have to run it through `json_decode`, e.g.

```
$body = json_decode($response['body'], true);
echo $body['top_secret'];
```

See the documentation for

- [`parse_str` — Parses the string into variables](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.parse-str.php) and
- [`json_decode` — Decodes a JSON string](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php)